# How to remove one or more instances of '?*' in a string using REGEXP_REPLACE function in oracle?

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, regexp-replace

I'm getting the characters `'?*'` one to three times in a column called Line. I am required to remove these characters. How do I do it using `Replace` or `REGEXP_REPLACE`?

```
SELECT
    Line, REGEXP_REPLACE(LINE,'[?*]','')--([^\+]+)
FROM
    TABLE
WHERE
    INSTR(LINE,'?*') != 0;
```

where

`REGEXP_REPLACE(LINE,'\?*','')` replaces the `?` alone and leaves the `*` untouched.

`REGEXP_REPLACE(LINE,'?*','')` replaces `nothing`.

`REGEXP_REPLACE(LINE,'[?*]','')` replaces all `?s` and all `*s`. I am only replacing when `?` and `*` comes together as `?*`.

Comment: Sample data (and desired output) might help us help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `(\?\*)` as pattern :

```
with tab(line) as
( 
 select 'abc?*ghh*?g?l*'  from dual union all
 select '?*U?KJ*H'        from dual union all
 select '*R5?4*&t?*frg?*' from dual
)
select regexp_replace(line,'(\?\*)') as "Result String"
  from tab;

Result String
-------------
abcghh*?g?l*
U?KJ*H
*R5?4*&tfrg
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/3vuNV1lq)</kbd>

Answer (score 4):

If you need the remove the string `'?*'`, you can use `replace`:

```
SQL> with test(string) as (
  2      select 'aa?*b?'            from dual union all
  3      select 'a*a?*??b?'         from dual union all
  4      select 'a*a??b???c*?**cc'  from dual union all
  5      select 'aa?b?*?cc?d??*?*?' from dual
  6  )
  7  select string, replace(string, '?*', '') as result
  8  from test;

STRING            RESULT
----------------- ---------------
aa?*b?            aab?
a*a?*??b?         a*a??b?
a*a??b???c*?**cc  a*a??b???c**cc
aa?b?*?cc?d??*?*? aa?b?cc?d??
```

Comment: This worked thanks. I assumed replace will only work in first occurrence and not subsequent occurrences.

Comment: @Arun [`replace`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/REPLACE.html) documentation